# How to hide the from email address from the receiver using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to programming. I want to send an email to the user, who cannot view my original from address, which is visible to him in the received mail.

Here is my code. Please guide me in what I have to to do to achieve that.

```
try
{
    MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
    // Sender e-mail address.
    Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text, "Rajesh", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    // Recipient e-mail address.
    Msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
    Msg.ReplyTo =new MailAddress("saro23988@yahoo.com");
    //Msg.ReplyTo = ("abc@gmail.com");
    Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text; 
    Msg.Body = txtBody.Text;
    Msg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    //txtUsername.Text,
    // your remote SMTP server IP.
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); 
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Credentials=new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text,txtpwd.Text);
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(Msg);
    Msg = null;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Mail sent successfully!.Thank god.');if(alert){ window.location='default.aspx';}", true);

    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript();
    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
    //Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Mail sent thank you...');window.close();</script>");

    //if(alert){ window.location='SendMail.aspx';}
    //}

    //Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Mail sent thank you...');if(alert){ window.location='default.aspx';}</script>");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
}
}
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: Open a separate account for the sole purpose of sending these messages?

Comment: so you ran this?  and what happens?

Comment: It sends the message correctly and the receiver receives the message from "saro23988@gmail.com", display name "Rajesh" and replyto send to "saro23988@yahoo.com" as per the coding. But my requirement is to hide the "saro23988@gmail.com" to receiver or to replace the email address.

Answer (score 7):

Well, here is something: you can not. Point. THere must be a valid email address.

And google really does not like people playing around with spamming - which is what you are technically doing. Google will not send your email with an arbitrary email.

Want to do that? Get your own server. And expect emails to just go where they belong - the trashcan.

Comment: not as good as the questions where they want the user to "not be able to close the window, or leave my page"

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the from address like in your code:

```
Msg.From = "anyNameIWant"
```

you are going to need to be sending from a different service other then gmail , and just about every single email service around will put this email right into spam if the from address doesn't match where it actually came from.

But , just hypothetically , say you had your own email server setup , and were writing emails to your own employees and want to change the from address , but not change the domain `@myurl.com` then you could probably get that working

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can make the From email whatever it is that you want. The recipient will still be able to see the server where it originated. When sending out notifications and such, I often make the from address something like "donotreply@mydomain.com." That way it's clear to the user that they shouldn't reply.